# Hardcoded date formats in predicate push-down?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If a date literal is used in a pushed-down filter expression, e.g.

```
val postingDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-06-03")
val count = jdbcDF.filter($"POSTINGDATE" === postingDate).count
```

where the `POSTINGDATE` column is of JDBC type Date, the resulting pushed-down SQL query looks like the following:

```
SELECT .. <columns> ... FROM <table> WHERE POSTINGDATE = '2016-06-03'
```

Specifically, the date is compiled into a string literal using the hardcoded yyyy-MM-dd format that `java.sql.Date.toString` emits. Note the implied string conversion for date (and timestamp) values in `JDBCRDD.compileValue`

```
/**
 * Converts value to SQL expression.
 */
private def compileValue(value: Any): Any = value match {
  case stringValue: String => s"'${escapeSql(stringValue)}'"
  case timestampValue: Timestamp => "'" + timestampValue + "'"
  case dateValue: Date => "'" + dateValue + "'"
  case arrayValue: Array[Any] => arrayValue.map(compileValue).mkString(", ")
  case _ => value
}
```

The resulting query fails if the database is expecting a different format for date string literals. For example, the default format for Oracle is 'dd-MMM-yy', so when the relation query is executed, it fails with a syntax error.

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
```

In some situations it may be possible to change the database's expected date format to match the Java format, but in our case we don't have control over that.

It seems like this kind of conversion ought to be going through some kind of vendor specific translation (e.g. through a `JDBCDialect`). I've filed a JIRA issue to that effect, but, meanwhile, I suggestions how to work around this? I've tried a variety of different approaches, both on the spark side and the JDBC side, but haven't come up with anything yet. This is a critical issue for us, as we're processing very large tables organized by date -- without pushdown, we end up pulling over the entire table for a Spark-side filter.

Comment: Could you pushdown a Date->String conversion with the Spark format via the filter? I.e. filter not on POSTINGDATE but POSTINGDATE cast to String equal to a correspondingly formatted String representation of the postingDate? Or will that not push down properly, since the index isn't used?